# How to fill 'requests' in Application Insights Analytics from HockeyApp in Xamarin app?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-application-insights, hockeyapp

I've just started using HockeyApp MetricsManager with Application Insigts Analytics on Azure. I managed to log customevents from my Xamarin App, but how can I log / trace requests?

I saw this requests table on this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-214-Hockey-App-and-Azure-App-Insights-with-Evgeny-Ternovsky-and-Josh-Weber

This is the tutorial I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcgHorMJklI&t=7s

My code limits to:

```
MetricsManager.Register(Application, "myAppId");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, requests is not a data type that is supported by HockeyApp. You can see more details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mobile-and-desktop-telemetry-in-application-insight-and-hockeyapp/. The demo that Josh and I did that you linked to included a requests table because the data that we were showing starting ~30min in came from a service that was instrumented with Application Insights. We did this just to show the potential of the Analytics tool with a big data set.

That said, HockeyApp does include a custom event mechanism that you can put any data you want into and then query via Analytics. You can see how to do this in section 3.7.2 [here](https://www.hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/4.1.2/docs/docs/Guide-Installation-Setup.html) - this link is for the iOS SDK but the same option is available for Android and Windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

1 Navigate to your application in the Azure portal.
   2 Click on the orange status bar saying Transfer to HockeyApp.
   3 Click the Transfer App button.
   4 Thats it!
    Behind the scenes the migration tool will use your Azure credentials to log in and create a HockeyApp account (if you don't already have one or it isn't linked to your Azure login credentials). It will then automatically provision a new HockeyApp app for you. This new app will be automatically linked with your Application Insights app. They will share the same instrumentationKey / appID and data sent via a AI or HA SDK will flow to both experiences until the June 15th sunset date for Application Insights. After that date data will only be available via HockeyApp.

Comment: Thx for Your answer Adit but I created my app(s) in Hockey App and then created new Application Insights with HockeyApp Id (Account Settings > API Tokens). This is the tutorial I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcgHorMJklI&t=7s